# Print the system memory structure

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, memory, hardware, virtual-memory

My system hosts 8 GB of RAM and 2 GB of VRAM. It runs Ubuntu 18.04 with  kernel `4.15.0-74-generic` `x86_64`.

IIUC, these two types of memory, in addition to the BIOS read-only memory, are mapped into the virtual and the physical address space.

Is there a tool to show how has this mapping been performed? In particular,  which ranges of physical/virtual addresses are located for the system RAM, which for the VRAM and which for the BIOS.

I don't know if `lsmem` is the right tool, because it seems not to distinguish between the types of memory.

---

**Edit**

About `lspci`:

```
$ lspci -v -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK107 [GeForce GTX 650]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at ee000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

The total amount of memory appears to be `16+256+32 = 304` MB, while [this card](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650/specifications) should have `1024` MB.

Comment: About virtual addresses: This will vary by process. Every process has its own virtual address. There can be two processes sharing the same physical memory, but have different virtual addresses (e.g. two processes have read/execute access to a library, and the library is mapped to different virtual addresses in the two processes). Reasons that the virtual addresses are different include: virtual address range in use, address randomisation, just because.

Answer (score 0):

You already found `lsmem`:

```
$ lsmem
```

Then, `lspci` will give the information about the graphic card's memory and mappings. First list the PCI bus:

```
$ lscpi
```

Identify your card (the numbers on the left). Let's say that it is listed as 00:02.0.

```
$ lspci -v -s 00:02.0
```

For the full video memory, that doesn't have to be mapped, you can do:

```
$ glxinfo | egrep -i 'device|memory'
```

Comment: Are you sure it is enough? I edited the question with a sample output of `lspci`.

Comment: I updated my answer. Note that the unused RAM will not be mapped. You could put it to another use though. For example [swap on video RAM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap_on_video_RAM). I'm not saying it is a good idea, just that it is possible.